# setState does not work in react hooks with context api?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io, react-hooks

I am receiving messages via `socket.io`, and I am listening for incoming messages inside `useEffect` hooks function.

Problem is when I update messages it does not update successfully.

```
export const GroupContext = React.createContext({});

function GroupProvider(props){

   const socket = useMemo(()=> io(url), [socket]);
   const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

   const setMessage = (message, room) => {
        if (messages[room] !== undefined){
           setMessages({ [room]: [message, ...messages[room]] });
        }
        else{
           setMessages({ [room]: [message] }); // updating messages per room
        }

        console.log('room: ', room); // I get the value: roomid100
        console.log('message: ', message); // I get the message: Hi dear, How are you
   }


   useEffect(() => {

      console.log('messages: ', messages); // But here I always get the last messages came.

   },[messages]);

   return (
        <GroupContext.Provider value={{socket,  messages, setMessage}}>
            {props.children}
        </GroupContext.Provider>
    );

}


function Group(props){

   const { socket, messages, setMessage } = useContext(GroupContext);

   const receiveMessages = ()=> {
       socket.on('getmessage', data => {
           setMessage(data.message, data.room);
       });
   }

   useEffect(()=> {

        if(socket.connected === true){

            receiveMessages();

        }else{
            socket.connect();
            setTimeout(() => {

               receiveMessages();

            }, 2000);
        }

        return ()=> unmoun();

    }, []);


    // ....

}


function Main(){
  // ....
  return (
        <GroupProvider>
            <Group />
        </GroupProvider>
  );

}
```

**Note: 
This same code works as well in Class Component without using hooks.**

Comment: Any error messages that you can share with us?

Comment: There is no error message, it just not able to update messages as you can see I am appending prev messages with current messages in a sperate room, so it is not appending or updating messages.

Comment: In your setmessage, change setMessages({ [room]: [message, ...messages[room]] });  to setMessages({ [ [message, ...messages[room]] }); } see if it works?

Comment: Or change to setMessages("test") to debug and see if you get any data there or no

Comment: `setMessages({ [ [message, ...messages[room]] });` this is not correct for seprating every room messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have two things:
1) setTimeout makes a closure for your `messages` variable (and it's why you see `{}`)
2) When you use `setMessages({a: 1})` you remove all others fields from `messages` state

So, you code will be executed in next order (code, where problems are highlighted):

```
function GroupProvider(props){

   const socket = useMemo(()=> io(url), [socket]);
   const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

   const setMessage = (message, room) => {
        // message = Hi dear, How are you, room: roomid100
        // messages: {}
        if (messages[room] !== undefined){
           setMessages({ [room]: [message, ...messages[room]] });
        }
        else{
           // Problem 1: Here you remove all other changes from you state
           setMessages({ [room]: [message] }); // updating messages per room
        }
        // Problem 2: Here you have a closure to your `messages` variable, so that it will be {}

        console.log('room: ', room); // I get the value: roomid100
        console.log('message: ', message); // I get the message: Hi dear, How are you
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('messages: ', messages); // But here always I get empty {}
        }, 2000);
   }


   return (
        <GroupContext.Provider value={{socket,  messages, setMessage}}>
            {props.children}
        </GroupContext.Provider>
    );

}
```

So you can fix it by using useEffect so that you can inspect your variable in the right way. And I suggest you to use `setMessages` as a function, to simplify your code:

```
function GroupProvider(props) {
    const socket = useMemo(() => io(url), [socket]);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

    const setMessage = (message, room) => {
        setMessages((messages) => {
            if (messages[room] !== undefined) {
                return { ...messages, [room]: [message, ...messages[room]] };
            }
            return { ...messages, [room]: [message] };
        });
    };

    // we will console log, when `messages` state changes
    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('messages: ', messages);
        },
        [messages]
    );

    return <GroupContext.Provider value={{ socket, messages, setMessage }}>{props.children}</GroupContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for `Problem 1` as you mentioned. But here the `else block` just executes for the first time, in second time `messages[room]` will not be `undefined`, and `if block` will be executed and messages gets append.

Comment: try to use `setState` which receives a function: `setMessages((messages) => {`
And I created a codesandbox example which is quite close to your problem (but without socket.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-khorana-w5pdr

Comment: Thank you very much problem is solved with the your code. Also I have removed `...messages` from `if block` like this:

`const setMessage = (message, room) => {
    setMessages(messages => {
      if (messages[room] !== undefined)
        return {[room]: [message, ...messages[room]] };
      else return { ...messages, [room]: [message] };
    });
  }`